# Building a GNN Model to handle variable no of node features in graphs

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I would like to build GNN model using PyTorch Geometric.

I originally tried to solve the problem of graphs with variable no of node features i.e., the matrix size of I/O data is different using dynamic graph, but when I researched more, it seems that the purpose of dynamic graph is not to learn matrices of different sizes flexibly.

In other words, suppose a full data with a matrix of edge nodes.
In this full data, each edge node is represented as 1 if it is connected or 0 if it is not connected.

And then we have data for training purposes.

All data is taken from full data. Full data is embedded as `19700 x 19700 x 50`, `float 32`.

```
Input data

A: 30 x 30 matrix
B: 500 x 500 matrix
C: 3 x 3 matrix
```

```
Output data

G: 24 x 24 matrix
N: 18 x 18 matrix
D: 94 x 94 matrix
```

I would like to ask if there exists any package/library that's appropriate to build GNN to learn matrices of different sizes as mentioned above?

I'm not a major and would appreciate it if you could point out any inappropriate parts such as terminology.

I used to use dynamic graph, but I found out while working that the tool is not intended for that purpose. So I was wondering if there is another way to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a package to do so. I would suggest you DIY by padding i.e., pad matrices with zeros to 30x30 size (maximum size model should learn from). I think padding should not have any negative impact. For reference you could have a look at my code [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/vasudevak/building-gnn-from-scratch) (9th cell, under the comment `# padding for compatibility with the model GNN`).

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.
My concern is that the difference in matrix size is huge, so I'm worried that the learning rate will drop a lot if I use zero padding.
I would like to ask you what you think about using autoencoder.

Comment: I think using autoencoder is not a bad idea but encoding 500x500 to 3x3 latent space might lead to loss of useful information. I would rather DOWN sample (using encoder) 500x500 matrices to 100x100 latent features and also UP sample (train a decoder network of transpose conv layers) 3x3, 30x30 matrices to 100x100 features. There may be other ways as well.

Comment: thank you for your idea. I will do that. thank you